# How to update model instance data in an ExtJS4 TreeStore

Tags: extjs, tree

I'm new to ExtJS and I'm using a TreePanel with a TreeStore which, in turn, uses a model that I've defined. The model is very simple and only consists of two fields: "name" (string) and "value" (integer).  My TreePanel has two columns: a treecolumn (which displays the "name" field of my model) and a gridcolumn (which displays the "value" field of my model).

My TreeStore is auto-loaded with JSON via an Ajax call. My JSON test data looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "coconut",
            "value": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

It's my understanding that by specifying a model for use with the TreeStore, it results in each model instance having NodeInterface properties/methods added to it so that it works with a tree structure.

In my controller, I've added an event handler for the TreePanel that fires when my user has clicks on a node in the TreePanel. That function looks like this:

```
onTreePanelItemClick: function(view, record, item, index, e) {
    console.log("Node name: " + record.data.name);
    console.log("Node value: " + record.data.value);
}
```

Everything is working properly to this point and when I click on the "apple" node in the tree, I see the expected output in the console:

```
Node name: apple
Node value: 1
```

Let's say that anytime my user clicks on a node in my tree, I want to update the "value" field for that node (or, perhaps more correctly, the "value" field on the underlying model instance) in the store so that it contains a "value" of 100.  To accomplish this, I've tried doing the following in my onTreePanelItemClick() function:

```
var selectedNode = myTreePanel.GetSelectionModel().getSelection();
selectedNode.data.value = 100;
```

Now, the first time I click on my "apple" node, I see the following in the console:

```
Node name: apple
Node value: 1
```

The second time I click on the "apple" node (after my onTreePanelItemClick() has updated the value to 100), I see this in the console:

```
Node name: apple
Node value: 100
```

Despite the console output, however, the "value" field that's displayed in the gridcolumn of my TreePanel still shows 1 (instead of 100).  I suspect that I'm not actually updating the model instance that underlies the node in my treestore properly.  But I'm not sure exactly *how* I'm supposed to update fields of existing nodes/models.  All of the examples I've seen for the TreeStore seem to deal with adding and removing nodes but that's not what I want to do.  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never access data of record via its (private) data property. Call record.get(), record.set() or record.getData().

In your case you would call record.set({value:100});